# setting env var values in deployed stream app

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

Using the following:

- Spring Cloud Data Flow Server Cloudfoundry 1.0.0.RC1
- Spring Cloud Config Server service

I rebuilt the spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry with the additional dependency to enable its binding with Spring Cloud Config server as the instructions provide.  It seems to be working as expected, so that's great.

The issue is arising now, when I attempt to define a stream with a custom module I developed, where the environment variables for the module (specifically ENCRYPT_KEY) are in a manifest YML file in my git repo.

The name of the manifest file is `customapp-dev.yml`. The manifest looks like this:

```
applications:
- name: customapp
  env: 
    ENCRYPT_KEY: keyForEncryption
```

The name of the properties file is `customapp-dev.properties`.  The properties file looks like this:

```
customapp.initial.context.factory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
customapp.ldap.provider.url=ldap://directory.xyz.com:389/dc=xyz,dc=com
customapp.username=ldap_user
customapp.password={cipher}958f87532ebba83cd81b7b0e9a0a0cc
```

The application has a properties file in the boot jar called `application.properties`.  It looks like this:

```
spring.application.name=customapp
```

Finally, when I deploy my stream, I provide one additional property in the command line like this:

```
--properties app.customapp.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

Tailing the logs of the app's deployment, I can see that the config server instance is being read, and that the app name and profile are being correctly resolved.  The config client is mapping both the YML manifest, and the properties file from my git repo.

However, the error is indicating there is no possible decryption for the placeholder `customapp.password`.

```
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2016-08-26T13:40:46.62-0600 [APP/0]      OUT  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2016-08-26T13:40:46.63-0600 [APP/0]      OUT  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)
2016-08-26T13:40:46.65-0600 [APP/0]      OUT Fetching config from server at: https://config-dfcc3100-7514-47e6-b30e-a0eefcf4929d.dev.xyz.com
2016-08-26T13:40:48.13-0600 [APP/0]      OUT Located environment: name=customapp, profiles=[dev, cloud], label=master, version=null
2016-08-26T13:40:48.13-0600 [APP/0]      OUT Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='https://user@bitbucket.xyz.com/scm/project/app-config.git/dev/customapp-dev.yml'], MapPropertySource [name='https://user@bitbucket.xyz.com/scm/project/app-config.git/dev/customapp-dev.properties']]]
2016-08-26T13:40:48.16-0600 [APP/0]      OUT Application startup failed
2016-08-26T13:40:48.16-0600 [APP/0]      OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot decrypt: key=customapp.password
```

If I explicitly set the ENCRYPT_KEY environment variable for the deployed (crashed) application, and restage it, it starts up fine and works like a charm.

Is there another way for me to specify the environment variables for a stream app at deployment time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I RTFM'd and found a useful excerpt in the existing documentation.

[Spring Cloud Config Server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server)

The command line specification at deploy time *will* work, but I was using the wrong syntax.  Instead of:

`app.customapp.ENCRYPT_KEY=keyForEncryption`

I should use:

`app.customapp.encrypt.key=keyForEncryption`

Answer (score 0):

The manifest (`customapp-dev.yml`) would not need to be in (the same) git repo as the rest of your config (as a matter of fact, it better not be, as it contains the decryption key).

More importantly, it's not clear from your question how you "use" it. Do you expect it to be taken into account automatically (thanks to config server, or anything) or do you indeed use it when you `cf push` your app?

The symptoms you're describing seem to indicate that the environment variable you set there is not taken into account (via manifest).

Comment: My expectations were that it would be loaded by config server automatically.  Since this is a stream app that gets deployed automatically when I deploy a stream, I'm not using `cf push` at all.  You're correct, the environment variable is not getting taking into account, so the decrypt is not happening at stream deployment time.

One thing I haven't tried yet, is to bundle the manifest in the app's JAR and hope it is read at deploy time.

Comment: Tried bundling the manifest in the app's boot jar, and got same error.  Why wouldn't using `app.customapp.ENCRYPT_KEY=key` on the deployment command line work in this case?  Is it because that is not a "known" environment variable?

Comment: To add to the manifest story: manifests are only used by the `cf (push)` command line app, at least as of now.